# Generalized linear mixed-effects modeling in R - How to interpret beta coefficients

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

I used the glmer function in the lme4 package in R to fit a generalized linear mixed-effects model (GLMM).

First, a brief description of the data/task:

Participants completed a simple task in which two patterns appeared on the screen - choosing one pattern ("S1") resulted in positive feedback and point gain and choosing the other pattern ("S2") resulted in negative feedback and no points.

The task consisted of 3 blocks of 40 trials (120 total trials). Halfway through each block, the 'correct' pattern became the incorrect pattern and vice versa. That is, S2 --> points and S1 --> no points. A new set of patterns was presented during each block.

I am interested in the effects of Trial (1-40), Time (Blocks 1-3), and Phase (first half of block/"Phase 1", second half of block/"Phase 2") on the odds of choosing S1 (S1 was coded as 1, S2 was coded as 0).

--

Here is the 'summary' output from R:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 0) ['glmerMod']
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Choice ~ Phase * Time * Trial - 1 + (Time + Phase + Trial + Trial:Phase + Time:Phase - 1 | Participant)
Data: dataSet.raw
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid
  4483.7   4670.8  -2212.9   4425.7     4651

Scaled residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-7.9797 -0.5177  0.1976  0.5535 16.6944

Random effects:
 Groups      Name         Variance  Std.Dev. Corr
 Participant Time          0.135609 0.36825
             Phase1        0.666153 0.81618  -0.71
             Phase2       10.484100 3.23792   0.25  0.10
             Trial         0.006032 0.07766  -0.02 -0.28  0.47
             Phase2:Trial  0.032282 0.17967  -0.04 -0.11 -0.86 -0.75
             Time:Phase2   0.745748 0.86357  -0.70  0.64 -0.16 -0.15 -0.09
Number of obs: 4680, groups:  Participant, 39

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
Phase1            -0.43696    0.29534  -1.480 0.139001
Phase2             5.75288    0.93310   6.165 7.03e-10 ***
Time               0.39126    0.13855   2.824 0.004743 **
Trial              0.18234    0.02985   6.108 1.01e-09 ***
Phase2:Time       -1.36899    0.40209  -3.405 0.000663 ***
Phase2:Trial      -0.40222    0.04799  -8.381  < 2e-16 ***
Time:Trial        -0.02767    0.01251  -2.211 0.027039 *
Phase2:Time:Trial  0.05444    0.01758   3.097 0.001955 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            Phase1 Phase2 Time   Trial  Phs2:Tm Phs2:Tr Tm:Trl
Phase2       0.025
Time        -0.881  0.059
Trial       -0.729  0.115  0.618
Phase2:Time  0.353 -0.707 -0.385 -0.234
Phase2:Tril  0.393 -0.750 -0.396 -0.706  0.560
Time:Trial   0.696 -0.004 -0.754 -0.833  0.264   0.522
Phs2:Tm:Trl -0.494  0.528  0.536  0.593 -0.795  -0.730  -0.716
```

Exponentiating fixed effects to get odds ratios:

```
exp(fixef(bestModel))

Phase1      Phase2        Time        Trial     Phase2:Time  Phase2:Trial   Time:Trial
 0.6459971  315.0972669   1.4788410   1.2000228 0.2543645    0.6688331      0.9727109

Phase2:Time:Trial
1.0559465
```

Here is my interpretation of the results (please let me know if this is correct):

**Phase2**: At Trial#1 and Time#1, there was a significant association between phase and choice. Greater odds of selecting S1 in Phase 2 versus Phase 1 (factor of 315.10)

**Time**: At Trial#1 in Phase 1, there was a significant association between time and choice, i.e., an increase in the time factor (block #) was associated with greater odds of selecting S1 (factor of 1.48)

**Trial**: At Time#1 in Phase 1, there was a significant association between trial and choice, i.e., increasing trials was associated with greater odds of selecting S1 (factor of 1.20)

***Significant interactions:***

**Phase2**:Time: At Trial#1, there was a different effect of Phase (1 versus 2) as time (block #) increased, i.e., decreasing odds of selecting S1 over time in Phase 2 (factor of 0.25)

**Phase2:Trial**: At Time#1, there was a different effect of Phase (1 versus 2) as trial # increased, i.e., decreasing odds of selecting S1 in Phase 2 (factor of 0.67)

**Time**:Trial: In Phase 1, there was a different effect of Time as trial # increased, i.e., no effect of Time in later trials (factor of 0.97)

**Phase2**:Time:Trial: the Phase(2)*Time interaction described above differed across trials - not sure how to interpret the odds ratio of 1.06 in this case.

Here are the predicted model probabilities to help you visualize the results:

[[image: predicted model probabilities:1]

Comment: What is your question?  (I don't see a "?" anywhere.)  Are you just asking us to proofread your interpretation of the results (ie, "please let me know if this is correct")?

Comment: My question is how to interpret the R output that I've provided. Instead of just posing the question, I also attempted to interpret the results myself. However, I am not sure whether my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Your model is incredibly complex. It is unusual to have a random slope for every predictor in the model. What is your justification for such an approach?

Comment: I compared models with different random-effects structures, including (1) a model containing only a random intercept of participant, (2) a maximal model containing random slopes for all predictors and interactions, and every possibility in between (e.g., a model containing only a random slope of Trial, one containing a random slope of Trial and Phase, etc.) I used AICc for model comparisons. So, to answer your question, the justification for that random-effects structure is that it was the model with the lowest AICc among those compared.

Comment: What you have done is a kind of p-value hacking. This is probably due to having read the "Keep it Maximal" paper by Barr et al (2013). If so, then either please try to forget everything you read in that paper, or read the paper by Bates et al (2015) "Parsimoneous mixed models" https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04967 . Note that Bates is the primary author of the `lme4` package you have used. As for interpretation, the only thing which differs between a logistic GLM and a logistic GLMM is that in the latter the fixed effects are conditional on the random effects.....[cont]

Comment: ...As such, you can make the same interpretations of the output as you would from a regular logisitic regression model for which there are hundreds if not thousands of questions with answers on this site. Regarding the interpretation of interactions, again there are many many answers here already.  The main thing I would suggest it to simplifty the random structure and use expert knowledge to specify what should or should not be random, provided it is supported by the data.